# Visual Studio extension that displays inherited custom attributes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, annotations, resharper, custom-attributes

Is there a Visual Studio extension or add-in that displays inherited custom attributes on types, properties and other targets?

For example if there is a base class like this:

```
[Serializable]
[SomeOtherAttribute]
[YeatAnotherAttribute]
class Person
{
    [IsRequired]
    [ShouldReturnNonNullNonEmptyString]
    public virtual string LifesGoal { get; }
}
```

Then I would like to see the inherited attributes when I subclass it:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| some sort of box displaying inherited attributes |
----------------------------------------------------
[SomeNewAttribute]
class Student : Person
{
    ----------------------------------------------------
    | some sort of box displaying inherited attributes |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    public override string LifesGoal { get { return "To study"; } }
}
```

Comment: No idea if any existing plugin does it. If you are interested, check out the <a href="http://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.ReSharper.SDK/">ReSharper SDK</a>, it certainly makes it possible.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Thank you for suggestion. I was thinking about ReSharper or Roslyn. Roslyn is unfortunately not ready yet, but as far as I remember they had some nice project templates for code analysis. Is there a good ReSharper contextual GUI plug-in sample project that I could use as a starting point? Something like those 'overriden' and 'recursion' hint icons that pop on the left side of code editor. Thanks.

Comment: Those are called gutter marks, and the following package includes a plugin example that, IIRC, supports gutter marks too: http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharper.SDK.8.1.555.msi

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk when I create a new plugin project the SDK NuGet package is added but the references are missing. Sometimes it is hard to figure out which assembly should be referenced based on missing namespaces. Any help? Thanks.